# What do "instances" in React.Perf correlate to?

Tags: reactjs

I'm having some issues trying to figure out what an instance is in reference to React.Perf. Do instances refer to the amount of times that component was created? Or does it refer to the amount of children components that the component created? Or something else entirely?

Thanks!